# Route requests as POST on Quasar (Vue3) client application

Tags: post, routes, vuejs3, vue-router, quasar-framework

So let me start by saying, yes, I have checked, and it seems impossible, at the time of writing this question.

What I am after is I want to be able to POST to my quasar (Vue3... same same) client, for example I have routes setup for /person/id: and so when I navigate to the url (GET) like:

```
http://localhost:9000/person/3
```

It loads the correct route and shows me the details for person 3. Now... What I want to do is route to the same place but not as a GET but rather as a POSt.

Why would you want to do that you ask... well the answer is quite simple. I have some information that I need to pass to the client, this information will be used when communicating to another server, the information is quite senstive and so I don't want to just pop it on the URL as a queryParam i.e.

```
http://localhost:9000/person/3?someSecret=superSecretValueDontTellTheFBI
```

So...based on the documentation I have gone through it appears you can't specify a POST routing table and the client application just rejects the POST request (Well at least when I am running it locally on my dev server using the quasar command `quasar dev`

I am hoping there is something I am missing, willing to try anything (except, wrap this call in a PHP page and then ...... , I cant wrap the call in any other page based on the current architecture in play.)

Comment: as you're figuring out, the idea of GET/POST routes for an SPA isn't accurate.  Vue-Router is completely _client side_, i.e. you can't send or receive backend information through just routes.  Your Vue component code however can _react_ to changes in the route and perform GET or POST fetch requests based on those changes.  [Watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) is a good tool for this, vue-router docs also include an [example](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api#Accessing-the-Router-and-current-Route-inside-setup)

Comment: Thanks will look into this. If it is fit for purpose I will reply again and then please feel free to pop an answer in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @yoduh. The suggestion hasn't quite worked for my use case but it did teach me something new. I'm going to close this question as I now see its like saying... I want to make blood come out of a stone... It shouldn't but... I want it :P